# Can't find the way to proper timeout or interval

Tags: javascript, timeout, pause

I can't find the way to timeout or pause (tried for and counting to big numbers) click event. I use *alert('x')* to stop before ***$(arr[i-1]).click();*** and then I have to press enter after that. But I want to automically pause after click event for about 300 ms.

```
javascript:
    var arr = $("a.farm_icon_b");
var x = document.getElementById("plunder_list").rows;
var images;

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var z = x[i].id;
        if (!!z) {

        images = document.getElementById(String(z)).getElementsByTagName('img');

        for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {  
                if (!!images) {

                if (images[j].src == "https://dspl.innogamescdn.com/8.116/36249/graphic/command/attack.png") {

                    if (images[j].tooltipText == "1 atak w drodze") {
                        alert('x');
                        $(arr[i - 1]).click(); 

                    } else if (images[j].tooltipText == "2 ataki w drodze") {
                        alert('y');
                        $(arr[i - 1]).click();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question's body in a DRY approach! There are more spaces than code :-)

Comment: Can you add a little more context about what is it that you are trying to achieve with this code? It looks like this code can be simplified considerably if the overall objective is clarified.

Comment: @Digitrance He's trying to build a JS script that automatically clicks some buttons in a browser game.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript setTimeout function to hold or stop your script to execute for time as per your requirement. check this [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for more details. All the best.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
   $(arr[i - 1]).click(); 
}, 3000); // 3000 is stands for 3 second you can change it according to your requirementcode here
```

Comment: Thanks Captain Obvious! I really know how to use Google.
I tried it for 2 hours and I didn't know how to do that.I wouldn't be writing if I know how to do that.

Comment: Let me try to help you for the same..

as per your code you want to stop the click event with alert okay if i understand this in correct manner so here is you solution.


use these code instead of alert.

setTimeout(function(){
    $(arr[i - 1]).click();
}, 3000); // 3000 is stands for 3 second you can change it according to your requirement.

Comment: check you browser console once fix it if there is any error.

Comment: So should I press  Ctrl+Shift+J  and run my script and check for error yes?

Comment: I forgot to add that I have to go to that website which I want to use it and then I click Chrome bookmark to run this script.

Comment: if you are using the google chrome just press F12 and reload the page u can check the error on console tab.

Comment: So there was no error and this way you proposed still doesn't work for me.

Comment: share the page link if its on live server or share the code i will check it.

Comment: But this script is for online game in special case so I think you couldn't check this.

Comment: I can only say that code :

_javascript:var arr=$("a.farm_icon_b"),i=0,t=setInterval(function(){$(arr[i++]).click();if(i>arr.length)clearInterval(t);},240);_

is working for that game but click all buttons. In my script only click that buttons when their image tooltip fulfills the condition


 _if (images[j].tooltipText == "1 atak w drodze") {_

Comment: Okay since i can't check your code but i can tell you how to debug and find the bug with your own... first check the value of arr, x, image hope you get it without any error then check on the loop along some static value like 2 or 3 max then repeat the same with inner loop you will find the error ... or u will if there any else went wrong.

Comment: @janek9971 Try this: http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/408779 (although not a great way to *pause* the execution in Javascript)

Comment: Thanks but my script is to click farm icon only if 1 attack is on the way to this village.

Answer (score -1):

**Important Note** (thanks to @Thomas for highlighting this) This function doesn't "sleep" for 300ms, it freezes the page. The browser simply is stuck in that loop for 300ms and can't do anything untill this is over.

---

I think this is the function you are looking for. It will help you put a 300ms delay before the button clicks.

```
function pausecomp(millis) 
{
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); } 
    while(curDate-date < millis);
}
```

*Source:* http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/408779

*Usage:*

```
pausecomp(300); // Sleep for 300ms
$(arr[i - 1]).click();
```

*Disclaimer:*

Ideally, a setTimeout() based solution is the best approach for such problems in Javascript (as suggested by Akansh). However, a linear for-loop based approach will most likely not work for such a solution, and you will need to devise a callback functions based solution that relies on deferred execution.

Comment: Thanks Man. Works but laggy too much. But like you said it is not good solution.

Comment: Yes, the lag is expected as the code runs sequentially in nested for-loops. Javascript is an event driven language, so the best JS solutions trigger and handle events (usually in parallel). Your solution can be rewritten to process the images in parallel, and still clicking the buttons with 300ms delay. With that solution, the lag will be minimal. Having said that, it all comes down to your requirements.

Comment: @Digitrance, please never use that. This function doesn't "sleep" for 300ms, it freezes the page. The browser simply is stuck in that loop for 300ms and can't do anything untill this is over.

Comment: @Thomas  Ye but works great for my usage. Sometimes it's important that something works :D

However I know that it shouldn't be used usually. Cheers

Comment: @Thomas why did you negative vote the answer? I clearly stated the Disclaimer in the answer and highlighted the fact that this is not at all a good solution.

Comment: @Thomas I've also added your comment as an important note to ensure future visitors are aware of the downside of this solution.